# Setup .htaccess for mvc front controller

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a simple question about the `.htaccess` file needed to setup a front controller.
What is the difference between this configuration:

```php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and this other:

```php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(css|js|icon|zip|rar|png|jpg|gif|pdf)$ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]`

This rule forwards all requests to index.php file, regardless of the requested file type

`RewriteRule !\.(css|js|icon|zip|rar|png|jpg|gif|pdf)$ index.php [L]`

Whereas this rule will only forward requests to index.php which are not in the list of specified extension.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. The second rule I've exposed, can be useful to avoid the `Uncaught syntax error unexpected token <` error when used for a front controller of an MVC pattern?

Comment: Are you referring to a PHP error? If so, no. A syntax error is truely what it says “an error in your code” which had no relation a .htaccess file

Comment: No, it's not a php error. I think that It can be related to the way that electron `php-server-manager` module load the resources, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: It’s best to create a separate question for that.

Comment: I did it, if you can help me to fix the error here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55429954/fix-uncaught-syntax-error-unexpected-token-in-electron